# asp.net C# passing value from gridview to texbox on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a simple gridview with button for each row, and I want to pass or display the value of user_full_name_ar in a label, I tried doing this using javascript function as shown below but it doesn't show the data it shows null,

gridview code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label5" Text='transfer text here' runat ="server" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="user_name" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="100px" Width="383px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_name" HeaderText="user_name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="user_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_full_name_ar" HeaderText="user_full_name_ar" SortExpression="user_full_name_ar" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="user_full_name_ar"  SortExpression="user_full_name_ar">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" Text='<%# Session["lang"].ToString() == "en"? Eval("user_full_name_en") : Eval("user_full_name_ar")  %>' runat ="server" />
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" text="select"  OnClientClick ="txt();" CommandArgument ='<%# Bind("user_name") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

javascript function to display value of label4 in gridview to label5 outside gridview :

```
<script  type ="text/javascript" >
    function txt() {

        var t = document.getElementById("Label4");
        document.getElementById("Label5") = t.value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a CommandField in gridview

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label5" Text='transfer text here' runat ="server" />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="user_name" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="100px" Width="383px">
    <Columns>
    <asp:CommandField HeaderText="select" SelectText="select " ShowSelectButton="True">
                          </asp:CommandField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_name" HeaderText="user_name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="user_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_full_name_ar" HeaderText="user_full_name_ar" SortExpression="user_full_name_ar" />

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="user_full_name_ar"  SortExpression="user_full_name_ar">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" Text='<%# Session["lang"].ToString() == "en"? Eval("user_full_name_en") : Eval("user_full_name_ar")  %>' runat ="server" />
                   </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" text="select"  OnClientClick ="txt();" CommandArgument ='<%# Bind("user_name") %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

after in selectedindexchenge event write code below

```
Label5.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
```